# Spring Webflux WebClient nested get

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm struggling with my `WebClient` implementation, which I call "sync operation"

I need to do a nested call because I have to fetch a list of project `IDs` and then call each project seperately by it's `ID` to get the full object into my `DB`.

My current working solution seems not to be clean, because I sometimes get "Operation timed out" and I need to get a notification when all projects are fetched/updated

Current solution

```
this.webClient.get()
    .uri(locationURI)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(LocationNevarisDto.class))
    .subscribe(locationDto -> {

        List<ProjectInfosNevarisDto> projectInfos = new ArrayList<>(locationDto.getProjektInfos());

        for (ProjectInfosNevarisDto projectInfosNevarisDto:projectInfos) {

            this.webClient.get()
                .uri(projectURI + projectInfosNevarisDto.getId())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(ProjectNevarisDto.class))
                .subscribe(projectNevaris -> {

                    if("AF".equals(projectNevaris.getStatus())) {
                        projectService.saveNevarisProject(projectNevaris);
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

`LocationNevarisDto` contains a list of projects and there `IDs`. I use this list and put it into a `foreach` and call get every project with its full attributes to save into my `DB`.

UDPATE:

```
@Data
public class LocationNevarisDto {

    private String id;
    private String bezeichnung;
    private DatenbankInfo datenbankInfo;

    @Data
    public static class DatenbankInfo {
        private String server;
        private String datenbank;
        private String benutzername;
    }

    private List<ProjectInfosNevarisDto> projektInfos;
}
```

Comment: Map it to a flux instead of a list, and issue a request using the flux, that way you will have parallel calls. Then subscribe to the flux which will inform you what happend.

Comment: This way I also have multiple calls, I updated my post and added the DTO of the first object to get a better understanding what I use as List

Comment: The point is if you would use a flux, your code would be cleaner.

Comment: would you mind providing an example, I'm new to webflux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use stream processing, so that your code is cleaner.

```
  public Mono<Void> doIt() {
    return this.webClient.get()
        .uri(locationURI)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(LocationNevarisDto.class))
        .flatMapIterable(LocationNevarisDto::projektInfos)
        .flatMap( this::saveProjectInfo).last();
  }

  private Mono<Void> saveProjectInfo(ProjectInfosNevarisDto dto) {
    return this.webClient.get()
        .uri(projectURI + dto.id())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(ProjectNevarisDto.class))
        .filter( (projectNevaris) -> Objects.equals("AF", projectNevaris.status()))
        .flatMap( projectService::saveNevarisProject);
  }
```

Something like this should do the trick. Using the `map`, `filter` and specialized methods to convert a mono into a flux you can have nice stream processing. One thing to keep in mind is that your whole chain and return types need to be reactive as well, else you might need some additional wrappings in `Mono.just` when calling the `saveNevarisProject`.

I also took the liberty to use `record` classes instead of classes and the lombok `@Data` annotation. However the gist of things should be clear with this.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a better understanding what is possible and how

Comment: Sorry, could you guide me on this aswell 

"One thing to keep in mind is that your whole chain and return types need to be reactive as well, else you might need some additional wrappings in Mono.just when calling the saveNevarisProject."

Comment: If your method returns `void` instead of `Mono<Void>` you need to wrap that call in `Mono.just` or `Mono.defer` or something like that to make it reactive.